# Is it possible to use Gmail as a postfix relay with virtual domains?

Tags: postfix, gmail, aliases

As I'm getting more and more frustrated with attempting to use sendmail to send web app emails that won't be flagged as spam, I've turned my attention to using postfix instead.  I've found [this Linode guide describing how to use Gmail as a relay for postfix](https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/configure-postfix-to-send-mail-using-gmail-and-google-apps-on-debian-or-ubuntu/), and it seems to tick most of the boxes - I have a Gmail account, so I could easily allow it as an external app on my account.

My question is this: will this work with virtual domains?  Meaning, if I have several web apps with their own limited (read: not in the sudo group) linux users, and these apps send emails out for various reasons, can I make it so that postfix's virtual domains/aliases work properly and that the emails' senders are `user@virtualhost.com` rather than `user@gmail.com`, or, even worse, `me@gmail.com`?

I don't want to install and configure postfix in this way if it's not going to work the way I need it to.

Comment: I do not use virtual domains however this github repo using postfix in a docker container ... it has an excellent active issue forum on their repo issue ... I use this for many domains and its a solid ecosystem https://github.com/tomav/docker-mailserver ...  my guess is at some point gmail will stop working as a relay when traffic exceeds some trigger so this repo might come in handy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you have a standard "end user" gmail account (`me@gmail.com`), not some Google Apps hosted domain.

In that case, GMail will rewrite all outgoing mails you send via your account so it will come from `me@gmail.com`, and not `user@example.com` in order to prevent you doing exactly that...

Comment: That's unfortunate... :-/

Comment: But absolutely necessary for Google. Otherwise they would be a semi-open relay, as anyone can sign up for GMail accounts...

Comment: Yeah, that's true